# "Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory" when trying to save a file

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm trying to create a json file using my website (that I will later deploy). This is the code I'm using

```
saveFile = (i, data) => {
  var filename = `${i}_may.json`;
  var folder_list = ["desktop", "data", filename];
  var dir = ".";
  folder_list.forEach(function (x, i) {
    dir = require("path").join(dir, `${x}`);
    if (!fs.existsSync(dir)) {
      fs.writeFileSync(dir, JSON.stringify(data));
    }
  });
};
```

But I keep getting this error

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'desktop\data'


  errno: -4058,
  syscall: 'open',
  code: 'ENOENT',
  path: 'desktop\\data'
```

Of course the folder exists in my desktop. Is there a way to make it works but in local and after the deployment?

Comment: You shouldn't use the sync methods for writing files. It will slow down your website.

Answer (score 1):

I dont see why you are using `forEach` if you ultimately want to execute the writing only once.

Also, using an absolute path is a better choice here. Regardless of your working dir, the script will always save the file in the correction location.

```
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');

saveFile = (i, data) => {
  var filename = `${i}_may.json`;
  var dir = path.join(process.env.HOME, "Desktop", "data", filename);
  fs.writeFileSync(dir, JSON.stringify(data));
};
```

Comment: thanks! this worked for when I run my code in localhost, but I'm getting this error when I deploy the website it on render:
"ReferenceError: path is not defined", why could it be?

Comment: @PisaPonente even though you imported `path`?

Answer (score 0):

To save a file to `[current_dir]\desktop\data`, you can use the following code:

```
saveFile = (i, data) => {
  const filename = `${i}_may.json`;
  const dir = require("path").join("desktop", "data", filename);
  console.log(dir);

  if (!fs.existsSync(dir)) {
    fs.writeFileSync(dir, JSON.stringify(data));
  }
};
```

Notice that the correct way to declare the path is to use `require("path").join('desktop','data',filename)`, which ensures that the path is properly constructed regardless of the platform you are running on.